# How can I open a Windows 10 app with a python script?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, automation, windows-10

So, as you may know there are certain apps on Windows that can be installed from the app store, and are classified as Windows Trusted Apps. I am not sure, but I think these do not use the classic .exe format. So I am writing a python script to automate some stuff when I start my pc, and I need to start a certain Windows App, but I don't know how to do this as I don't know what I need to start to do so, and I also do not know where these files are located. Anyone can help?

Comment: Is it enough to manually create a shell shortcut out of the virtual `shell:appsfolder` and have your script run it via `os.startfile`? Or do you need to fully automate finding the app's `IDList` in order to shell execute it?

Comment: @eryksun the issue I am having is that I totally do not know where the file is actually located...

Comment: You're not supposed to reference these apps by the executable. Eventually there is one of one sort or another -- typically in a subdirectory of the hidden system folder `%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps`. Some apps support a URL protocol, like `bingnews:`, that you can use in Explorer or cmd's `start`. Otherwise you need the application user model ID (AUMID) for use with the `IApplicationActivationManager` COM interface. If you create a shortcut  (i.e. a .lnk file) on your desktop from one of the apps in `shell:appsfolder` it contains the AUMID, and you can use `os.startfile` to run the shortcut.

Comment: @eryksun thanks for the reply and explanation!

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I found a way to run Windows Universal apps which downloaded via Windows Store or preinstalled.
Each Windows 10 Universal app has an `AUMID` which stands for 'Application User Model ID'.

**PowerShell** Command to get all AUMID:

```
get-StartApps
```

Output:

> ```
> PS C:\> get-StartApps
>
> Name                      AppID
> ----                      -----
> Skype                     Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
> Snip & Sketch             Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Mail                      microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Calendar                  microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.w...
> Movies & TV               Microsoft.ZuneVideo_8wekyb3d8bbwe!Microsoft.ZuneVideo
> OneNote for Windows 10    Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe!microsoft.onenoteim
> Photos                    Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Video Editor              Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!SecondaryEntry
> Maps                      Microsoft.WindowsMaps_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Alarms & Clock            Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Voice Recorder            Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Feedback Hub              Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Xbox Game Bar             Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Camera                    Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Microsoft Store           Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Weather                   Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Cortana                   Microsoft.549981C3F5F10_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
> Instagram                 Facebook.InstagramBeta_8xx8rvfyw5nnt!Instagram
> ...
> ```

So now, you can start any universal app via its AUMID like this:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\[AUMID]
```

For example, if you want to execute `Skype`:

```
explorer shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
```

Now it's the time to back to Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('start explorer shell:appsfolder\Microsoft.BingWeather_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App')
```

The `Windows Weather` App will execute.

Happy Coding

Comment: This is crazy good.

Comment: You can also do this inline with Powershell only with a subshell since `startapps` aka the `Get-StartApps` PS cmdlet. To open Docker Desktop if it isn't running `explorer shell:appsfolder\"$(startapps docker* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty AppID)"` with the only caveat since it automatically wildcards, you want to be as specific as possible, ie `startapps 'xbox game'` because `startapps xbox` returns multiple results. You could also use `Select-Object -First 1` or `-Last 1` if you *know* there are only a couple results and the order is predictable.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.system('start D:\\bharat\\sqldeveloper.exe')
```

For Windows cmd this [start path/app.exe] will open the app
so just use the full path of the exe of required file (make sure to use  `\\` in path while writing python script)

Comment: The command `start D:\\bharat\\sqldeveloper.exe` doesn't work on Win10 CLI, only Powershell, and even with that, you have to run `start` first, then `D:\\bharat\\sqldeveloper.exe`. Another issue is `os.system()` is not the recommended way to do this. The better option is `subprocess.call()` to spawn a new process. Lastly, in Python3, the double-slashes are not required when a real string is prefaced with `r`, as in `r'D:\bharat\sqldeveloper.exe'`. This keeps syntax as close to bash as possible, so no need to escape the forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else ever faces the issue:

you can start most windows apps in cmd with the following syntax:

```
start [program]:
```

ex:

```
start Netflix:
```

Keeping this in mind, to port to pythn simply use the following code:

```
import os
os.system('start Netflix:')
```

replace with your program of choice and voila :)

Comment: This is not working. Windows 10 app cannot be ran from cmd like this. I tried with Instagram.

Comment: this does not work with some apps like camera, photos etc

Comment: This `start appname:` trick will only work for apps that have a `URI schema` registered. Netflix has `netflix://` registered and Spotify and many others might as well, but it definitely isn't universal to all apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this new technique, its called winapps its used for searching, modifying, and uninstalling apps. Its download command on cmd windows is `pip install winapps`.