# How to control Windows context menu with code?

Tags: windows, winapi

For example, I want to open a docx file with right click -> context menu -> open.

I know some libs like `pygetwindow`/`pyautogui` can do something like this.

```
import pyautogui
import pygetwindow as gw

win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('xxx')[0]

win.activate()

left, top, width, height = win.left, win.top, win.width, win.height

right_click_pos = (left + width // 2, top + height // 2)

pyautogui.click(right_click_pos, button='right')

pyautogui.time.sleep(1)

pyautogui.move((0, 20))  
pyautogui.click()
```

But I want it to be more robust, to give a menu tree if possible, not locating buttons with pixel.
Any code example would be of great help. Javascript (or any language) if possible. I am working with a playwright project.

Edit: Maybe Windows API with C++/C#? I've only learned the basic of it...

Comment: If you just want to launch the app, pyautogui seems inappropriate. Does [How can I open a Windows 10 app with a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696735/how-can-i-open-a-windows-10-app-with-a-python-script) answer your question?

Comment: @ggorlen well my purpose is not just luanch it. I need to check the memu for certain options, therefore need to access the menu tree.

Comment: @mplungjan sorry if I got it wrong, I just thought it would be nice if javascript can hundle this since I am working with playwright. Do you recommend deleting all language related tags here?

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. In general, it's frowned upon to put more than a language tag or two--people tend to see that as casting too broad a net, but I'll leave it up to you.

Comment: You can read the registry, but it depends on which option you are looking for. Can you add more detail, what option do you need to locate and "click"?

Comment: @CherryDT that option is not standard in Windows, which basicly like open but in a seprate sandbox. So I might need a general solution for any option.

Comment: A solution for "any option" will be needlessly (and very) complicated because it's not a simple menu with a list of options, it is loaded from different sources including dynamic ones that involve calling third party libraries. Please specify which software creates this option and how it looks (does it have an icon? A sub menu? Etc) and on what file type(s) this option exists and I'll try and help you track down how that specific option could be called without using the menu.

Comment: Basically I'm smelling an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info) here - what you ask is "how can I list context menu items for files and programmatically invoke one of the options" (which is very complicated and probably not even necessary) but what you really want is "how can I programmatically invoke feature X of program Y which also shows up in context menus" (which will probably be very simple and straight-forward once we know what this feature and this program are).

Comment: [`ShellExecuteExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw) is the system service that opens a file using the associated default application.

Comment: Yes but depending on what context menu option the OP needs and whether it's a simple association verb or a shell extension we may need a specific approach.

Comment: @CherryDT Thank you. I checked the reg table, it's a KEY from`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\sandbox\command`. the value is `"C:\Program\SandMan.exe" /box:__ask__ "%1" %*`, I think I will just use this command instead of trying to access it from context menu.

Comment: You could try to [create shortcut Menu Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers)
Shortcut menu handlers can provide their own canonical verbs through IContextMenu::GetCommandString with GCS_VERBW, or GCS_VERBA. The system will use the canonical verbs as the second parameter (lpOperation) passed to ShellExecute, and is the CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO.lpVerb member passed to the IContextMenu::InvokeCommand method.

Comment: @李舜生 That's what I meant. You figured the exact solution out yourself now!